# Can I prevent rsync from checksumming its link-dest files?

Tags: backup, rsync

I'm using rsync (version 3.0.9) to do snapshot-style incremental backup from local disk to a LAN-attached NAS that's mounted using cifs. The functionality is ideal, but it's unreasonably slow for the most common scenario: daily backup of a file hierarchy (~100GB, ~2000 directories) in which only a very few files have changed. The slowdown does *not* happen when doing the simple:

```
rsync -a /home/stuff/ /mnt/nas/backup/yesterday
```

(when only a few files have changed since yesterday) because in this case rsync uses only its quick timestamp+size check to compare files. But when I do my snapshot backup:

```
rsync -a --link-dest=/mnt/nas/backup/yesterday /home/stuff/ /mnt/nas/backup/today
```

there is heavy network traffic to/from the NAS and things go very slowly even though almost no data is actually transferred from source to target. I suspect this is caused by rsync checksumming the target files in the link-dest directory. Adding `--no-checksum` doesn't alter things. Is there any way to get rsync to do its file compare as quickly when doing link-dest as it does when doing a simple overwrite?

Comment: Afterthought: obviously creating all the required hard links within the NAS filesystem will have some overhead. But the amount of traffic I'm observing is commensurate with rsync reading the *contents* of all the link-dest files.

Comment: Follow-up to my afterthought: I wrote a short script that created links, on the NAS file system, to all the files in a link-dest directory - and then deleted them all again. It ran in only a few seconds, and generated far less network traffic to/from the NAS than the `rsync --link-dest`. So I stand by my conclusion that rsync is scanning the entire contents of the old target files.